# Infinite scroll in a WK-Webview (Next.js)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, local-storage, intersection-observer

To maintain scroll position, I retrieve the data stored in local storage. There are no speed issues in environments other than the app, but the app experiences speed issues and overheating (very slow). The issue occurs when returning to the list that has stored values in the storage from the view page. I am using IntersectionObserver, and the local storage contains the list array, page number, total count, scroll Y value, and filters in JSON format. If you need the relevant code, I can provide it. This is a translation of the previous Korean text into English. Thank you.

I had developed scroll position maintenance for infinite scroll, and it worked very well on the web. It did not excessively consume JavaScript memory. However, issues arose specifically on the web.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.